# How should I choose a screen cleaning solution?

Tags: display, cleaning

I saw the thread about cleaning screens with distilled water and a microfiber cloth, but if I want to get a specialized screen cleaning solution, what factors/properties should I look for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't waste money on solution, diluting vinegar with water works great.

Comment: Upvoted but would love proof

Comment: well using the terms vinegar, computer, and monitor on google will show results about cleaning, if that is sufficient for you... http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=vinegar+computer+monitor&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&fp=7e6f8db6d1d62ff2

Comment: One more vote for the (water+one of those soft cloths that come with glasses) solution. I've seen people do a whole afternoon discussions about cleaning solutions, only to have the same result afterwards. Like selling fog to scotts.

Comment: @John I'd like google to point me here though ;)

Comment: Hmmm, in the video at today's second hit at Google, http://www.videojug.com/film/how-to-clean-your-computer-with-vinegar, the screen itself is not touched at all. Also, the order in which the cleaning is done is a bit odd... *"Begin wiping down cables, mouse, keyboard and monitor."* But well, it's just one out of many hits. (I use a damp cloth with a tiny bit of handsoap -- no problems so far.)

Answer (score 4):

I often just use plain old Water (H2O). Absolutely no worries about it harming the coating on the screen and it gets the job done perfectly.

Comment: Works great with plain old cotton cloth.

Comment: I have tried both cotton and microfiber cloths with just plain water, and find that microfiber cloths do a better job of getting that last little bit of water off the screen, leaving less residue.

Answer (score 2):

As you wanted a vendor recommendation, a few years ago I collected 20 something odd cleaning solutions for TFT screens and personally tested them all for a few weeks at the office. In the end, [Disko](http://www.disko.com/english/products-engl.html) one-time use set was the clear winner by far (though also one of the more expensive). Their "wet" cloth was simply amazing, extremely thick and soaked like a sponge compared to other wet cloths that were usually just a damp and thin piece of paper-like material.

These days I'd go for just any microfibre cloth though and some water or if really deluxe, some vendors own cleaning solution which by experience perhaps'd be Disko as well, just for kicks or nostalgia ;)

[image]

Comment: I'd love to hear if the upvotes are from people who also prefer Disko, or if it's just that my answer is somehow nice in its own merit ^^

Answer (score 1):

A recent episode of [HD Nation](http://revision3.com/hdnation/screenclean) talks about cleaning HDTV screens.

They recommend using a microfiber cloth that is damp with distilled water.

For tougher cleaning they recommend creating a 50/50 mix of distilled water with isopropyl alcohol (don't use any scented variations)

I've found water and a microfiber cloth have always worked great - I don't like the thought of using a mix of alcohol or vinegar even though they're probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

No "cleaning liquids" ever.
You don't know what the screen may be coated with, nor what will dissolve that off in seconds.
Water & soft microfibre only.

*Copied directly from my own answer at [Ask Different - Cleaning my Macbook Pro Retina leaves greasy 'streaks' across the screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230065/cleaning-my-macbook-pro-retina-leaves-greasy-streaks-across-the-screen/230067)*

Two microfibre cloths, available from any supermarket.
Don't get the 'smooth' ones specially for glass, they can be a bit hard on a plastic screen, get the 'fluffy' ones that make your fingers itch, like picking up tiny velcro.

One cloth completely wetted in lukewarm water [nothing else], then squeezed as dry as you possibly can [trick - fold in 4, then roll & wring. You really want it as dry as possible].
The other cloth totally dry.
If the screen is warm, you may need the first cloth very slightly wetter - but never anywhere near wet enough to dribble if squeezed - you really don't want any water that could run down the screen. The cloths work better when almost dry anyway.
If the screen is cold & also dark, i.e. computer off, you'll also find it much easier to see when it's clean.

Wipe the damp one gently over the screen, multiple times, turning the cloth, pay attention to the edges & corners. The trick is gentle repetition, rather than 'force'. 
Then, whilst the screen is still very slightly damp, wipe over again with the dry one, completely drying the surface.

Smears gone forever… well, until next time ;-)

*Please don't be tempted to use any type of domestic cleaner or alcohol. You never know what type of screen coating any given screen has & some cleaners can irreparably damage the coating layer of some screens.*

Answer (score -1):

Some window cleaning "spray thing" that I get in the supermarket.

They have different names depending what country you live in, but its all the same stuff.

However since lcd monitors have a "plastic" feeling I'm a little bit cautious my self, 
since I got the feeling that they scratch easy... So I think the cloth is more important than the liquid.

Comment: Need to use a nonabrasive liquid though... like many alcohols don't qualify...

Comment: This could ruin any coated screen in seconds. Avoid.

Answer (score -1):

I bought the [Philips LCD/Plasma Screen Cleaner Kit](http://www.consumer.philips.com/consumer/en/us/consumer/cc/_language_us/_productid_SVC2543W_27_US_CONSUMER) (SVC2543W/10), cloth included and it seems to do the job nicely.

[image: "phillips screen cleaner"]

Comment: That cloth is potentially too hard for plastic - plasma screens are glass & not easily scratched.