# Is this cleaning product safe to use on the screen of my laptop?

Tags: laptop, cleaning

This is the [link](https://www.amazon.es/Limpiador-pantalla-Toalla-microfibra-30x30cm/dp/B00DX7GLW8/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=limpieza+port%C3%A1til&qid=1569276727&sr=8-5) to the product.
This is the [link](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX504/specifications/) to my laptop specs.

If you don't want to go there, I'll just paste the display specs here:
15.6" FHD (1920x1080/16:9) LED Retroiluminado 120Hz 300nits 3ms

I think that's all. If you need more info, comment and I'll edit this question. Also, If you want to recommend another product that's better or cheaper maybe, you cando it. I'm from Spain btw, just in case, for the shipping.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Products made for glass screens tend to stain LCD/LED ones. This in particular is probably one of the worse and obscenely expensive.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Do you know about appropiate products for LED screens?

Comment: Yes,  a clean nonstatic cloth :)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia but do I need to use some liquid or something? Or just with the cloth it's enough?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/23062/how-should-i-choose-a-screen-cleaning-solution?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I choose a screen cleaning solution?](https://superuser.com/questions/23062/how-should-i-choose-a-screen-cleaning-solution)

Comment: BTW, if you decide to use a liquid, *do not put it on the screen*, just on the cloth.

Comment: I've copied my answer to the potential dupe. I've seen too many coated screens destroyed by using 'cleaners'. Some solvents are fine on all screens, some are not. You find out when you strip the coating :\

Answer (score 1):

A clean microfiber cloth with a little bit of clean water has proven really effective for me. I wouldn't mess with vinegar or other stuff - could mess with delicate coatings, and/or leave residue. Get one corner of the microfiber a bit wet, and use that to wipe the whole screen - gets off fingerprints, etc. Then use the dry part of the cloth to completely dry the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Although the product is *probably* safe on computer screens it's not really necessary. As you will never know what coating may be on the screen nor what would dissolve it in seconds, why even risk it?
Microfibre & water alone will do the job just fine.
Microfibre actually doesn't 'like' being used with any kind of detergent cleaner, it clogs the fibres & makes them less effective.

*Copied directly from my own answer at [Ask Different - Cleaning my Macbook Pro Retina leaves greasy 'streaks' across the screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230065/cleaning-my-macbook-pro-retina-leaves-greasy-streaks-across-the-screen/230067)*

Two microfibre cloths, available from any supermarket.
Don't get the 'smooth' ones specially for glass, they can be a bit hard on a plastic screen, get the 'fluffy' ones that make your fingers itch, like picking up tiny velcro.

One cloth completely wetted in lukewarm water [nothing else], then squeezed as dry as you possibly can [trick - fold in 4, then roll & wring. You really want it as dry as possible].
The other cloth totally dry.
If the screen is warm, you may need the first cloth very slightly wetter - but never anywhere near wet enough to dribble if squeezed - you really don't want any water that could run down the screen. The cloths work better when almost dry anyway.
If the screen is cold & also dark, i.e. computer off, you'll also find it much easier to see when it's clean.

Wipe the damp one gently over the screen, multiple times, turning the cloth, pay attention to the edges & corners. The trick is gentle repetition, rather than 'force'. 
Then, whilst the screen is still very slightly damp, wipe over again with the dry one, completely drying the surface.

Smears gone forever… well, until next time ;-)

*Please don't be tempted to use any type of domestic cleaner or alcohol. You never know what type of screen coating any given screen has & some cleaners can irreparably damage the coating layer of some screens.*

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop's [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/GamingNB/FX504GM/E14566_FX504GM_V2_A.pdf) states on page 11:
[image: Manual Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

I have used a soft cloth or J-cloth . Make very wet, add a drop or two of “green “ dish detergent, work into suds, wring out excess water, clean the screen and keyboard. Just suds - no excess water. Wet the cloth to remove all suds and wring out the water and wipe off the suds. This cleans, removes grease and fingerprints and does not damage screens. I have done this for years on many computers and iPhones. Free (assuming you wash dishes)