# Monitor Cleaning: Is it okay to use light cleaner on wet microfiber cloth?

Tags: display, cleaning

I sprayed some light 409 Household Cleaner on a wet Microfiber cloth to clean my 2 Year old monitor screen.

Lot of websites, say not to do that.  Other resources say its okay to use Isopropeyl alcohol, or cleaning solution, on damp cloth. I did Not spray on Monitor directly.

Monitor technology has changed, what is the standard cleaning practice now?

409 has around 9-11 ph Level.

**Resources:**

[CNET Cleaning](https://www.cnet.com/tech/home-entertainment/how-to-clean-your-monitor-or-tv-screen/)

[Dell Care Instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000125321/cleaning-and-maintenance-recommendations-for-the-dell-c7017t-monitor-touch-glass)

[HGTV Care](https://www.hgtv.com/lifestyle/clean-and-organize/how-to-clean-a-computer-screen)

Note: I could not use standard water, I had food particles sticking to monitor :)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1485697/347380 BTW, just naming a brand not available worldwide means most people [including me] will have no idea what might be in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chemical safety data sheet (SDS) for [Formula 409® Multi-Surface Cleaner](https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/sds/formula-409-multi-surface-cleaner/) is readily available, stating it contains alkyl (C12 40; C14 50%; C16, 10%) dimethyl benzyl ammonium chloride, [quaternary ammonium compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_ammonium_cation). Unlike ethyl or isopropyl alcohol or similar cleaners, these alkyl compounds *do not* evaporate, and leave a thin film on the surface of the monitor. Further, they may be hygroscopic, "pulling" water out of the air into any electronic circuits they've onto which they've been sprayed.

Since you were careful *not* to spray the monitor itself, only the cloth, likely you've done no harm -- you can judge that yourself, if the monitor appears to be working. However, I'd follow up by using a cloth moistened with alcohol, distilled water or glass cleaner to remove the remaining chemicals.

Another question is the [health effects of these compounds](https://go.drugbank.com/drugs/DB11202), such as contact dermatitis, asthma or respiratory symptoms, as well as [long-term environmental and health issues](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7341688/). Of course, this is *not* the site for such a question, which might belong on [Chemistry StackExchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ok, since I used it on the monitor screen, and it leaves a residue, let me wipe a dry microfiber cloth over it, one more time, thanks

Comment: Microfibre is not designed to be used dry. It needs water to work. [The two cloth method in my link above is reliant on the surface still being wet from the first cloth.]