# How do you keep your laptop keyboard from staining the screen?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, lcd

I have a ThinkPad T400 and the TrackPoint and keys leave stains on the LCD.

How do you keep the stains off your laptop screen? And, are there any keyboard stain-specific tips in addition to the suggestions at [another SuperUser thread about cleaning LCDs](https://superuser.com/questions/8326/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-an-lcd-monitor-display)?

[image: LaptopLogic photograph of the keyboard]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of paper between the keys and screen works wonders - just stick it in when you close the lid, and it's highly inexpensive!

(Plus you can write a to-do list on it, so you notice it more easily)

Comment: And just don't make it a habit of keeping anything BUT that piece of paper between your keyboard and screen. One day you leave a pen, and ... :|

Answer (score 1):

I really would **not** use paper... The wood fibres scratch both the screen and keys, the same reason paper tissues are advised against using on your glasses.

I've taken a large, thin microfiber cleaning cloth (the solid kind, not woven!) and cut it to size for my laptop (for a straight cut use a metal ruler that you press down on the fabric, and when sizing take into account hinge space at the top). This has kept both sides in pristine condition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To keep the stains off your laptop screen in the first place, [paper](https://superuser.com/a/93351/1646029) was suggested as a solution.

I do prefer [kitchen towels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_towel), as they provide some additional features:

- they are dust-absorbing
- provide protection against pressure/shocks from outside because of their softness
- long and soft fibres agains ripping and scratching (in contrast to reaular or toilet paper)

In my case, I just folded them, so that I got 3 layers in total and it works perfectly for a 17" Laptop with a sensible (4k, nonglare) screen. YMMV, depending on your model, you might need more or less layers. Cut and fold according to your needed size.