# Tips for cleaning touch screen

Tags: cleaning, tablet, touchscreen, windows-tabletpc, touch-pc

Is cleaning a touch screen LCD any different to cleaning normal LCD?

Should one avoid using window cleaner solutions as well?

Is distilled water and microfiber the only recommended method?

Touch screen gets touched much more (obviously) and greasy so a different solution might be better suited.

Comment: See this: http://www.ehow.com/how_6565943_clean-lcd-touch-screen.html

Comment: Very similar question http://superuser.com/questions/8326/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-an-lcd-monitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_6565943_clean-lcd-touch-screen.html) has a useful article on this subject:

> **Things you'll need:**
>
> - Soft cotton cloth
> - Distilled water
> - 2 soft, lint-free cloths
>
> **Instructions:**
>
> 1. Turn off the touch screen, and unplug it from the power source.
>      Keeping the power on while cleaning the screen can damage it.
> 2. Dampen a soft cotton cloth with distilled water and wring it out.
>      For extra cleaning power, use a solution that is specially designed
>      for touch screens. You can find these cleaners at most office supply
>      and electronics stores.
> 3. Use the damp cloth to wipe down the entire screen. Use a gentle
>      sweeping motion from top to bottom, and never apply pressure to the
>      screen, because that could cause permanent damage.
> 4. Dust the screen with a dry, lint-free cloth to remove any leftover
>      fuzz or dust.
>
> **Warning:** Avoid spraying cleansers directly on the screen, as this
>   may cause permanent damage.