# How to clean a stubborn LCD panel?

Tags: display, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to clean an LCD monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/8326/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-an-lcd-monitor)

I invested in some good IPS panels a few months ago and today is the first time I've tried cleaning them. I have a microfiber cloth and it go all of the dust off, but one of the screens inexplicably had something sticky/gummy on it and the cloth couldn't get it off. I tried putting some tap water on the cloth and using it again, but it just kind of smeared it around.

I'm afraid of damaging my expensive panel and am not quite sure what to do. I've seen screen cleaning stuff at Wal-Mart and on Amazon, but I'm worried it might still damage my panels.

Advice?

Comment: Don't use tap water. There are special fluids available to clean LCDs. I got one from my nearest HP store. So if you have a Dell/HP/Acer center near by, buy from there. They will also be able to guide you