# How to clean an anti-glare or matte display?

Tags: display, cleaning, anti-glare

I have a Thinkpad T530 laptop. I tried to clean it, but it has streaks, and a solution I was looking at on Newegg said it was *not* for displays with an anti-glare coating.

I'd like to know, with respect to anti-glare/matte displays in particular:

1. What I should use to clean the screen, and
2. How I should use it.

Comment: Here is a similar question: [What is the best way to clean an LCD monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/8326/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-an-lcd-monitor)

Comment: this shouldn't be a duplicate, since it is asked specifically on the anti-glare and matte displays, which is not answered in the referred question. Voting for re-open

Answer (score 1):

Microfibre cloth and diluted rubbing alcohol.

See link for more info: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-4A2P54

Answer (score 1):

Microfibre cloth is the basis for the cleaning. Make sure that it does not contain some residues from manufacturing like traces of oil. You can wash it in warm water with detergent but rinse it thoroughly.

Do not press too hard. This order of cleaning is safe in most cases. If the cleaning step is not enough I continue with the next one. Use step 3. only when necessary. In most cases distilled water is enough.

1. dry microfibre cloth
2. microfibre cloth dampened with distilled water
3. microfibre cloth dampened with 25% solution of pure isopropyl alcohol (rubbing alcohol) in distilled water