# Is it okay to use stuff like kerosene and gasoline to clean a PCs display?

Tags: display, cleaning

It is cheaper, no necessary to buy something else, cleans very well. But how good it is for display ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to clean an LCD monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/8326/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-an-lcd-monitor) & note... never use anything other than water. If the screen is coated one wipe with the wrong stuff will kill the coating, permanently.

Answer (score 7):

No, gasoline will dissolve many kinds of plastics and coatings, and you don't know exactly what's on the surface of your display.  Use a clean, slightly damp cloth to clean PC displays.  You can use a very small amount of mild detergent or specialized "display cleaner", but never spray directly onto a flatscreen display.  Water gets under the bezel and never gets out, and seeps in between the layers of the flatscreen, making it ugly at best and shorting it out at worst.

Comment: I've used rubbing alcohol many times with a cotton ball and start with a small corner area first to test just in case but I've never had any problem with rubbing alcohol and a soft cotton ball cleaning computer screens from LCDs, plasma, old CRT too. Not sure what you think about rubbing alcohol but I think it's the S%^$ for cleaning computer monitors. I've also used the slightly damp cloth method many times as well so +1 Chris Hostage

Comment: Isopropyl alcohol (IPA) is terrific at removing oils (like from fingerprints). But I would not use the stuff labeled _rubbing alcohol_ as it contains perfumes and oils intended to make "alcohol rubs" more enjoyable for the patient. (This was also a good reason to not use it for cleaning tape heads back in the day.) Fortunately, most larger drug stores do carry 70% isopropyl alcohol, which is the same alcohol concentration as "rubbing alcohol" but without the perfumes and oils. The premoistened "computer screen wipes" usually include some IPA, though I don't know the concentration.

Answer (score 1):

in short, no. you cant as this can damage your'e screen try a proper screen cleaning tool / liquid (Eg: a cloth)